# How to correct "first error: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector" when using parApply?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am attempting to use parApply to analyze a 41x1000 matrix of data by row. The following are the functions that I am using:

```
library(signal)

custom_filtfilt <- function(trial, a, b){

  y = filter(b, a, c(trial, numeric(2 * max(length(a), length(b)))))
  y = rev(filter(b, a, rev(y)))[seq_along(trial)]
  return(y)

}
```

```
filtered_data <- parApply(cl, trial_surr_ds, 1, custom_filtfilt, bf_filters[[f]]$a, bf_filters[[f]]$b)
```

I tested this on a local machine and it was working fine but I need to move it to a computational cluster with 80 processors to speed up processing. Now I am getting the following error message:

```
41 nodes produced errors; first error: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

When I change the margin of the parallel call, I get the following:

```
filtered_data <- parApply(cl, trial_surr_ds, 2, custom_filtfilt, bf_filters[[f]]$a, bf_filters[[f]]$b)
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  80 nodes produced errors; first error: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

So it seems the data is being read correctly in the first call since only 41 nodes are processing the data for this call but, for some reason, it seems that it is not recognizing the input from the matrix supplied for parApply. Any idea what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to have been an issue with exporting the correct data matrix to each node in the cluster. The following code fixed it:

```
filtered_data <- parApply(cl, trial_surr_ds, 1, function(x) custom_filtfilt(x, a=bf_filters[[f]]$a, b=bf_filters[[f]]$b))
```